# Undefined variable in the JS Scope in a object literal

Tags: javascript

I have the following Code (http://jsbin.com/disofaji/1/):

```
var test = {
  person: "nick",

  init: function() {
    $('#foo').click(function() {
      // how to access the person? 
      console.log(this.person);
    });
  },

};

test.init();
```

the problem is, that I get the output `undefined` and I want to know how to access the `person` inside my click handler.

NOTE: the click handler is only an example for my problem, I have it in a other context too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because inside your click handler, this actually refers to the control that triggered the event.

I have updated your code, and it works. Here is what you're required to do

```
var test = {
  person: "nick",

  init: function() {
    var obj = this;
    $('#foo').click(function() {
      // how to access the person? 
      alert("inside");
      console.log(obj.person);
    });
  },

};


test.init();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a well known "trick" to preserve a reference to the original scope of the function:

```
init: function() {
  var self = this;
  $( '#foo' ).click( function() {
    console.log( self.person );
  } );
},
```

Basically, you'll want to "cache" the `this` variable into another variable (in this case called `self`). Then, inside your click handler, you can access the `self` variable as if it was the `this` variable outside of your click handler.

---

Another option would be to simply use backbone's event delegation:

```
var test = {

  events: {
    "click #foo": "foo_click_handler"
  }

  person: "nick",

  foo_click_handler: function() {
      // callback is bound to the view scope, so "this" can be used normally.
      console.log( this.person );
  },

};
```

From [the docs](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents):

> All attached callbacks are bound to the view before being handed off to jQuery, so when the callbacks are invoked, `this` continues to refer to the view object.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `var self = this;` ie. saving a reference to your object, or other event libraries I would use [bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) (included in JavaScript standard library) which will make your code more concise and a bit more modular.

What bind does is that it takes the function `logperson` and binds it on to whatever object you pass it, in our case `this`.

This does remove you from the use of an anonymous function however, which for my personal preference, is always better.

```
var logperson = function() {
    console.log(this.person);
};

var test = {
    person: "nick",

    init: function() {

        $('#foo').click(logperson.bind(this));

    };
 };
```